# How to disable the "clear log messages" functionality for administrators?

Tags: 7, log-messages

For a production site, for auditing purposes, I would like to disable the "clear log messages" functionality for all administrators. This function is shown within admin/reports/dblog (within the "Recent log messages" report).

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use hook_form_alter, and either remove that form or put access control on it. This needs to happen in a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

A quick css display:none on the form will do it, assuming you trust your administrators enough to not go into "inspect element" and turn it back on again.